# Can laravel make password encryption like mysql password() function?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

how do I make password encryption on Laravel PHP to look like Mysql password() encryption? is there a way to do that? so I can create user to MySql using query on Laravel eloquent, and logged in to MySql using the user I create with Laravel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't. because we can't get MySQL user tables using eloquent (AFAIK)

But you can create mysql user using query (but you need to set DB config to root/admin user first)

example:

```
$user = "youruser";
$pass = "yourpassword";

DB::statement(DB::raw("CREATE USER '$user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '$pass'");
DB::statement(DB::raw("GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO '$user'@'localhost'");
```

and to use as your app db config:

```
Config::set('database.connections.mysql.user', $user);
Config::set('database.connections.mysql.password', $yourpassword);
```

You can do anything with new created user after that. example to call migration:

```
Artisan::call("migrate --database=mysql");
```

Comment: what if i already make config on database.php and i called it mysql7, and how i do the raw query with the config? when should I call DB::connection('mysql7'). sorry im still new on laravel, can you give some example? should i do DB::connection('mysql7')->statement(DB::raw...) like this?

Comment: i tried and i got this error SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1396 Operation CREATE USER failed, when i try create on mysql the create command works fine, can you help me with this?

Comment: `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1396` usually mean the user is already created, try other username

Comment: let me know your mysql7 config

Comment: sorry for late reply, problem already solved, thanks alot